# Navigation drawer closes on configuration change

Tags: android, drawerlayout, navigation-drawer

In my fragment, I am programmatically adding a fragment into the navigation drawer, then opening the drawer from the right. Note that I do not have direct access to the xml file for the DrawerLayout and thus require a programmatic solution. The drawer opens from the right and closes correctly, and I preserve the drawer's open/close state and open it once the configuration has changed based on that state.

The issue is, on configuration change, the drawer closes (I can see the drawer animating to the closed state), even when I restore its open/closestate based on the savedInstanceState boolean. I placed a debugger in all of the `closeDrawer` methods in `DrawerLayout.class` but they're not being hit.

**UPDATE**: I think I see where the issue is, but I'm not sure how to resolve this without extending the DrawerLayout itself. `DrawerLayout#findDrawerWithGravity` which is called in the `DrawerLayout#onRestoreInstanceState` is returning null in my case.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(STATE_DRAWER_OPEN,
        getDrawerLayout() == null ? false : getDrawerLayout().isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT));
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        isDrawerOpen = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_DRAWER_OPEN);
}

private void setDrawer() //this is called in onCreate
{
    DrawerLayout drawer = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer == null)
        drawer = getDrawerLayout();

    View existing = drawer.findViewById(R.id.m_drawer_container);
    if (existing != null)
        drawer.removeView(existing);

    drawer.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(this);

    FrameLayout fragmentContainer = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
    fragmentContainer.setId(R.id.m_drawer_container);
    final DrawerLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(
        getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.m_drawer_max_width),
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.RIGHT);
    drawer.addView(fragmentContainer, layoutParams);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    MyDrawerFragment mDrawerFragment = null;
    Fragment frag = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_DRAWER_FRAGMENT);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if (frag != null && frag.isAdded())
        fragmentTransaction.remove(frag);
    mDrawerFragment = MyDrawerFragment.newInstance(myArgs);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.m_drawer_container, drawerFragment, TAG_DRAWER_FRAGMENT);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

    if (isDrawerOpen)
        drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the answer was calling `drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT, false);` to disable animations when it's a restore from config change. The reason is that calling `drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT)` has animation set to true by default, and digging into that method eventually results in this block of code in `DrawerLayout.java`, which causes an incorrect width calculation, resulting in the drawer being "hidden":

**DrawerLayout.java**

```
else if (animate) {
    lp.openState |= LayoutParams.FLAG_IS_OPENING;

    if (checkDrawerViewAbsoluteGravity(drawerView, Gravity.LEFT)) {
        mLeftDragger.smoothSlideViewTo(drawerView, 0, drawerView.getTop());
    } else {
        mRightDragger.smoothSlideViewTo(drawerView, getWidth() - drawerView.getWidth(),
                drawerView.getTop());
    }
```

The solution is to set animate to false when restoring from configuration change.

```
if (isDrawerOpen && isRestoreFromConfigChange)
    drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT, false);
```